# How can I stop Chrome from blocking mixed downloads (really)?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome is blocking mixed downloads. That means a situation where a website uses HTTPS for their main web site, but downloads are coming from plain HTTP.

[Various technical articles](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-stop-chrome-from-blocking-downloads#:%7E:text=You%20can%20stop%20Google%20Chrome,section%20of%20Chrome%27s%20Settings%20page.) claim that by going to "Privacy and Security" settings, you can turn this off, but I had no luck. As you can see by the screen shot below, I have it set to "No Protection", but it is still blocking downloads:

[image]

Comment: if you click next (up arrow) to the blocked icon, you can select "keep"

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow Insecure Content for the website that contains
the mixed downloads:

- Open the website
- Click on the icon to the left of the website address
- Select "Site settings"
- Scroll down to "Insecure Content", it will contain "Block (default)"
- Set the drop-down box to "Allow".

As Chrome is hardening its security policies from year to year,
I don't know how long this will continue to work.

Comment: I am hoping for a global solution. Normally I rarely download more than one or two documents from a particular web site, so changing settings for individual websites would be tedious.

Comment: I wouldn't expect many websites to offer HTTP downloads nowadays. I haven't met any such for quite some time.